# Select columns based on dynamic table value parameters?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql, table-valued-parameters

I'm trying to build a stored procedure that will be dynamic as possible:

I'd like to pass the values of the select statement as parameters which can have a variable number of parameters, then perform the select by those parameters, e.g.

`select @column1, @column5, @column8 from myTable`

`@column1, @column5, @column8` - Those should be passed as **one** parameter to the stored procedure, where the number of parameters can vary.

How do I write this kind of stored procedure?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Might as well generate the adhoc SQL strings in your application. Can't see what benefit doing this in a stored procedure gives you.

Comment: are these variables going to be the column names ?

Comment: @MartinSmith - I had a feeling that writing it in a stored procedure would leave me with a clearer code on my application (instead of concatenating string 'select ' + String.Join(",", columnList) + '...'.

Comment: @M.Ali - yes, the variables will be the column names.

Comment: Whether or not you end up doing it in SQL you shouldn't use `String.Join(",", columnList)` anyway if this input is in anyway untrusted. You need to make sure that the column names are quoted in `[]` and any `]` characters are doubled up to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @MartinSmith - I think this method will only move the mess from the client code into T-SQL, not perform as well, and be less secure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_selectColumns
  @Var1   SYSNAME = NULL
 ,@Var2   SYSNAME = NULL 
 ,@Var3   SYSNAME = NULL
 ,@Var4   SYSNAME = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Columns = ', ' 
                 + CASE WHEN @Var1 IS NOT NULL THEN QUOTENAME(@Var1) + N', ' ELSE N' ' END
                 + CASE WHEN @Var2 IS NOT NULL THEN QUOTENAME(@Var2) + N', ' ELSE N' ' END
                 + CASE WHEN @Var3 IS NOT NULL THEN QUOTENAME(@Var3) + N', ' ELSE N' ' END
                 + CASE WHEN @Var4 IS NOT NULL THEN QUOTENAME(@Var4) + N', ' ELSE N' ' END


SET @Columns = LEFT(STUFF(@Columns, 1, 2,''), LEN(STUFF(@Columns, 1, 2,'')) -1)



        SET @Sql = N'SELECT ' + @Columns + ' FROM dbo.TableName'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

### Using a Table Valued Parameter

### Table Type

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.ColumnNames AS TABLE
(
  ColumnName SYSNAME
)
GO
```

### Procedure Definition

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_selectColumns_TVP
 @ColumnName AS dbo.ColumnNames READONLY 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Columns NVARCHAR(MAX);
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @Columns = STUFF((SELECT ', ' + QUOTENAME(ColumnName)
                         FROM @ColumnNames
                         FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
                         .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,'')

        SET @Sql = N'SELECT ' + @Columns + ' FROM dbo.TableName'

        EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql

END
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if I might have 20 columns (This would look kind of messy..)? That's why I thought I could use table valued parameters somehow?

Comment: another twenty columns mean another twenty Case statements, Not messy at all, always indent you code nicely and no matter if you have thousands of rows in your code it will always look clean and easier to read. :)

Comment: @BornToCode have a look now I have update my answer to make use of a TVP and yes will decrease the line of code require to do the same thing :)

Comment: I'm sorry for nagging, but this just returned a null result, also how can this work for multiple (unknown number of) columns in addition to `ColumnName SYSNAME`

Comment: You Declare a variable of `dbo.ColumnNames` type , populate that variable with values (column names of your table), and finally pass that table variable to this procedure.

Comment: Thank you, you should just change `SELECT @Columns` into `SET @Columns`